# React.js & Flux - where is the best place to register Websocket event (receive data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I'm trying to write a simple application that should display a list of items received from Firebase DB, using Websockets. 
To receive data I should listen to firebase events, something like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase("firebase-url-here");

ref.on('value', function(snap) {
    console.log(snap.val());
});
```

My question is - where is the correct location to register this event?

I read this great [article](http://blog.andrewray.me/flux-for-stupid-people/) about Flux - in the comments section there is an answer from Facebook engineer saying receiving data will be via store's getData method. On the other hand, on [Facebook's Todolist](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#content) tutorial there is an option for 'handleServerAction' which should handle server actions. I understand the concept that actions should be dispatched from view and from server (as view actions and server actions).

View actions will be dispatched from user interactions on the view file. I do not understand where is the place to dispatch server actions from (assuming I want to use the 'handleServerAction' method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how I'd do it (in case of Flux): You should put your WebSocket into Web API module. Create socket `init` action (to initialize WebSocket) and `push` action (to send data via socket). Make Web API module to dispatch an action on data income, listen for this action in the store and update the store once you get some data. Then you can dispatch `init` action from within root component and listen to store changes in components where you need the data. Also you can dispatch `push` action when you need to send data over the socket.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds reasonable. Is there a "Flux" way of doing so? Is there a best practice/tutorial showing this way? And one question: When you say "dispatch init action from within root component" - I do not understand why this should be a dispatch, rather than a simple init method of this module. Thanks again!

Comment: This is looks pretty Fluxish for me, but yeah, there might be a better way, I can't point you to any of examples. I think you are right about `init` action, this looks more like a simple function call rather than data transfer.